# W3C Validation - Why is the <header> tag not accepted?

Tags: html, css, header, w3c

I am trying to validate my webpages using the W3C validator and it is returning an error whenever I use:

```
<header>Page Title</header>
```

The error message it is giving is:

> element "header" undefined

I know I can use `<h1>` instead but was just curious why this isn't accepted?

Comment: Post all of your code

Comment: My guess is a bad `doctype`.

Comment: The doctype I am using is: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">, which I believe is the default for Dreamweaver

Comment: That explains why... my guess was correct. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `doctype` you are using (XHTML 1.0 Strict) is incorrect, since the `<header>` tag is new to HTML 5.

Replace:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

With:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Revalidate, and job's a good'un!

Answer (score 2):

This is a valid markup for me

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <!-- <-- Watch out for this -->
<html lang="en">
   <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8" />
     <title>Demo</title>
   </head>
   <body>
     <header>
       Hello
     </header>
   </body>
</html>
```

Make sure you are not using `<header>` tags as page title, and also you are misunderstanding `header` with an `h1`, `h1` element is to represent the main header of the page, which represents what type of stuff your page holds, like about us, our services etc, where `header` tag is used to say that yeah this is my page header which will be rendered on all pages, which generally have `nav` for navigation/menu, logo, etc

Comment: Weird, as far as I remember, it was valid back then. What's the issue? DM in the chat and will try to sort it out :)

Comment: @MrAlien The OP was asking about XHTML, and the double dash in the comment is not well formed XML.